# How to Restart a Stuck App Update?

Tags: 8.0, apps, nokia-lumia-920, update

My download of the Smart Shoot app (a Nokia camera lens on the 920) failed when it needed an update last week. Since then, it displays an "attention required, tap to retry" message. When I tap, it downloads halfway and then fails again.

I am unable to cancel the app or uninstall Smart Shoot completely because those options are greyed out.

Comment: are you connected to wifi or are your trying to download over the network. Try connecting to a wifi and download the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried both on wifi and over the network. Originally, I was downloading over 4G, but I've retried on both.

Answer (score 2):

I think in downloads hold down on it then 'cancel download' .  Then try and download the app again.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but the 'cancel download' option was greyed out. After about a month, the pending download did go away on its own, and I was able to re-initiate the update.